# How Does One Make Apache htaccess 301 Redirects Absolute?

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

I am trying to redirect my university webpage with an .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /~foo/ http://mynewdomain.com/
```

However, instead of taking me to http://mynewdomain.com , it appends the ~foo so that it redirects to http://mynewdomain.com/~foo.

How does one make it to redirect to only http://mynewdomain.com?

PS: Actually, I believe by default it redirects to http://mynewdomain.com , maybe there is a setting our admin has changed, and I need to revert it?

I have also tried other combinations like:

```
Redirect 301 / http://mynewdomain.com/

Redirect 301 /~foo http://mynewdomain.com/
```

but they all redirect to http://mynewdomain.com/~foo

Comment: Use `wget -S` to see what's actually being thrown back at you.

Comment: It looks like this is related to the UserDir setting in Apache.

Comment: Redirect 301 /~foo http://mynewdomain.com/
works actually, there was some problem with caching. Make sure you try this in a new browser if the redirection doesn't work.